# My Nameservers reset with linux restart

Tags: linux, networking, centos

I have the centos 6.4.

I have nameservers defined in `etc/resolv.conf` like this

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

Every time when my computer restrats that file gets reset to empty and i have to write that again

why is that

Comment: What is the content of the file after a reboot?

Comment: As it stands your level of knowledge really is below what we would expect from a professional Linux sysadmin. I think you need to speak to your manager about getting some education, it will benefit both you and your company.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about basic unix/linux which does not fall under this site's [help/on-topic]

Comment: @lain I think that was bit harsh. i am not highly professional and i am learning to become professional like you

Answer (score 2):

Your resolv.conf appears to get updated due to an IP assignment via DHCP. You can either fix the DNS server on the DHCP side or prevent your resolv.conf from being changed every time you get a new DHCP lease as described in the [CentOS Documentation](http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/s1-networkscripts-interfaces.html). Just use the PEERDNS option.

Answer (score -1):

This is most likely due to DHCP, you're getting a new IP address every time you reboot.

Install resolvconf and run it.

Comment: This is not Ubuntu.